# Provide additional platform.dependent .dll with .Net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll

I have an application (.Net 4.6.1, WPF) that is requiring a specific .dll (not managed) on the production system to run. The DLL is available in two versions (x64 and x86). How can (should) I pack the DLLs in my project for different platforms?

Of course, there is the possibility to create two projects, one targetting only x64, one x86 respectively, but I would like to avoid that overhead.

Ideally, I was thinking of something like a folder structure as

```
cwd/
    app.exe
    component.dll
    lib/
        x86/
            provided.dll
        x64/
            provided.dll
```

where the application at startup loads the correct provided DLL depending on the runtime platform (x64/x86).

Unfortunately, I cannot change the Assembly loading of the application itself (done automatically at startup).

Regarding the search paths, I checked [1], but could not find platform-specific loading information.

Is there a way (best practice) to achieve this?

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

Comment: You need to, one way or another, distribute your application along with the x64 dll to 64-bit systems and vice versa. How do you currently deploy the app?

Comment: Currently, the app is deployed by coping over the optimized release build along with the needed DLLs. In the current production environment, there are only x64 devices, such that the main application (Any CPU) along with the DLL for x64 is running fine. There are new systems being deployed at site with x64 and x86 architectures (Win 7 and Win 10). The application should be runnable on both systems loading the correct DLL automagically.

Comment: As I have no control on the loading sequence itself it would be best to have the DLL in both versions packed in the (sub)folder and the runtime linker can select the right one. Question is, whether this is possible or do I need to provide different binaries of my application for it?

Comment: If you can't modify the code you will have to provide different binaries. But this shouldn't be a problem if you manually copy over the app files. Just provide two versions of the app; one 32-bit and one 64-bit version.

Comment: @mm8 I was afraid of that... I was hoping for another solution on linker level - Thank you for clearing things up - have a nice day!

Comment: Drop x64 build of the native dependency to %windir%\system32, and x86 build to %windir%\sysWOW64. That's the common practice (DLL hell as well).

Answer (score 0):

It has some way to do it.

The easy way to do it makes the DLL compile as Any CPU that can use in x86 and x64 but your dll is not managed that may can't compile as Any CPU.

Another way to do it using Macro. Add the difference Macro in x86 and x64 like add `x86` in x86.

And you can write the code to load difference DLL.

```
#if x86
        public const string DLL_FILE_NAME = "DLL_32.dll";
#else
        public const string DLL_FILE_NAME = "DLL_64.dll";
#endif

        [DllImport(DLL_FILE_NAME, EntryPoint = "Foo", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int Foo1(int var1, int var2);
```

The other way to do it uses two methods that call the x64 and x86.

```
    [DllImport("DLL_32.dll", EntryPoint = "Foo",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int Foo32(int txcuiwKjvwu, int hhmzfadnHexkmr);

    [DllImport("DLL_64.dll", EntryPoint = "Foo",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int Foo64(int txcuiwKjvwu, int hhmzfadnHexkmr);
```

You can use `Environment.Is64BitProcess` to get the application as x86 or x64.

```
   public int Foo(int txcuiwKjvwu, int hhmzfadnHexkmr)
    {
        if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        {
            return Foo64(txcuiwKjvwu, hhmzfadnHexkmr);
        }

        return Foo32(txcuiwKjvwu, hhmzfadnHexkmr);
    }
```

The lastest but not least is using `SetDllDirectory` to set the directory.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string path);
   var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
      path = Path.Combine(path, Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86");
      SetDllDirectory(path);
```

To set the Path to find the DLL can easy to load some not managed DLL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but these solutions need the change of the process of assembly loading which I have no control of (externally provided code, loading the assembly at startup by name).
When placing the FooX64.dll in the same folder, it is found, but crashes with badimage for x86 runtimes and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, I cannot change the Assembly loading of the application itself (done automatically at startup).

Then you are stuck with deploying the application along with the approriate DLL.

You could provide two versions of your app; one 32-bit version that includes `x86/provided.dll` and another 64-bit version that includes `x64/provided.dll`. The users will then have to install the appropriate version based on their CPU architecture.